# How to correctly implement "hamburger" to back button functionality when using Fragments

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

How to move to a new fragment and automatically have the "hamburger" menu change to a `<-` button which brings the user back to the previous menu?

This seems to be an arcane art, no matter how many stackoverflow questions I read and things I try the "hamburger" menu always just opens the drawer. I am getting confused with certain posts using backstacklisteners to change icons, others using the onoptionselected and others directly attaching a click listener.

## Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
        private ActionBar actionBar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setToolbar();
            // show first fragment here
        }

        private void setToolbar() {
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
                drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
                drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                drawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mnuSettings:
                showSettingsFragment();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void showSettingsFragment() {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragHolder, new SettingsFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

## Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="@color/primary"
                 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                 app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
                 app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <FrameLayout
                 android:id="@+id/pnlSearch"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_margin="8dp">

                <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="44dp"
                     android:background="#FAFAFA"
                     android:gravity="center"
                     android:hint="@string/search_hint"
                     android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionDone"
                     android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                     android:maxLines="1"
                     android:textSize="16sp"/>

                <ImageView
                     android:layout_width="24dp"
                     android:layout_height="24dp"
                     android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                     android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                     android:alpha="0.2"
                     android:contentDescription="@string/magnifying_glass_icon"
                     android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"/>

                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                     android:layout_width="24dp"
                     android:layout_height="24dp"
                     android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                     android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                     android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                     android:alpha="0.5"
                     android:background="@drawable/ic_clear_black_24dp"
                     android:visibility="gone"/>

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
             android:id="@+id/fragHolder"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
         app:menu="@menu/toolbar_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

## SettingsFragment:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setToolbarTitle();
    }

    private void setToolbarTitle() {
        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(R.string.settings);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is the standard way to acheive this and not to start adding click/backstack listeners without understanding how its *really* meant to be done.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity write this function:

```
public static void setUpIndicator(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(appCompatActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha, null));
        else
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(appCompatActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
```

Call this function inside your fragment's onCreate.

Comment: The interesting part is the `setNavigationOnClickListener` in your code. So if this is the way its to be done, what about all of those tutorials / posts on the web which suggest handling the `R.id.home` item click in options?

Comment: R.id.home you mean menu options?

Answer (score 0):

You should animate the **hamburger**

call method like

For Animate hamburger to back arrow

> below should call before wherever you call add or replace `fragment`

```
animateBurgerToArrow(mDrawerLayout, 1, 0);
```

in your **Activity**

**From your comment**:

> onOptionsItemSelected is never called from the fragment

Solution!! : ***return false*** in activity's `onOptionsItemSelected` `onclick` of `Home`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
             return false; 
        case R.id.mnuSettings:
            animateBurgerToArrow(mDrawerLayout, 1, 0);
            showSettingsFragment();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Animate back arrow to hamburger

> below should call before wherever you call popBackStack

```
animateBurgerToArrow(mDrawerLayout, 0, 1);
```

in your **SettingsFragment**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            animateBurgerToArrow(mDrawerLayout, 0, 1);
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**Method**

```
private void animateBurgerToArrow(final View drawerView,int start,int end){
    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(start,end);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            mDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
    });
    anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    // You can change this duration to more closely match that of the default animation.
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.start();
}
```

Comment: My question was more about how to get the *back* functionality working in the *correct* way.

Comment: what i understand from `automatically have the "hamburger" menu change to a <- button`

Comment: It does not need animation for that, `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` serves that purpose.

Comment: Apart from the animation the rest of the code is the same as I already have, which does not work, ie. the onOptionsItemSelected is never called from the fragment on the hamburger click, the drawer just automatically opens.

Answer (score 0):

Mike M.'s answer helped me immensly. Once I had it working I slowly removed code until the wrapper was half its size, then I realised the whole thing was working because of one line:

`toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`

At which point, I thought it best to remove the wrapper altogether and use the following code to acheive the same functionality. I feel this is the best way to go about it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener
...
private void setToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    boolean onHomeScreen = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0;
    drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(onHomeScreen);
}
```

And if I wanted to get rid of the title setting code in the detail fragments, or any fragments which add to the backstack I could do:

```
if (!onHomeScreen) {
    String fragmentTitle = getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragHolder)
            .getClass()
            .getSimpleName()
            .replaceAll("(\\p{Ll})(\\p{Lu})", "$1 $2")
            .replace("Fragment", "");
    actionBar.setTitle(fragmentTitle);
}
```

This would make the `SettingsFragment` have the title of `Settings` and `UserDetailsFragment` to `User Details`.